# smbclient linux / os x nt_status_pipe_broken

Tags: linux, macos, debian, virtualbox, samba

I try to connect with a Debian on a shared folder in Mac Os X Mavericks with samba.

I try this : smbclient -L //192.168.0.1 -U myUser

I have got following error :

tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_PIPE_BROKEN

I use virtualbox, os x is host and debian the guest, i don't want use share folder virtualbox, it 's too slow.

Can you help me ? Thank

Comment: I use smbclient 3.6.6

Comment: Maybe consider using `NFS` to share rather than `SMB` since both OSes are more Unix-y than Windows-y.

Comment: i tried this solution, but i have not been able mount NFS share. I use the tutorial http://www.brianwcook.com/2013/02/serving-nfs-to-guests-using-virtualbox.html

Comment: Maybe this will help... http://thomaspolasek.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/linux-mount-osx-nfs-share.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os X not use SMB signing.

You can use this solution :

```
smbclient -L //192.168.0.1 -U myUser --signing=off
```